# how to handdle the error System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: The added or subtracted value results in an un-representable DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime

I have create one helper method that convert UTC date time to specific time zone datetime.

```
 public DateTime ConvertToSpecificTimeZone(DateTime utcDateTime, string utcOffset)
 {
      return ConvertTimeZone(utcDateTime, utcOffset.Trim());
 }
 private DateTime ConvertTimeZone(DateTime dateTime, string timeOffset)
 {
            int offsetSign = (timeOffset.StartsWith("-") ? -1 : 1);
            timeOffset = timeOffset.TrimStart('+').TrimStart('-');
            if (timeOffset == "00:00")
            {
                return dateTime;
            }
            else
            {
                string[] offsetArgs = timeOffset.Split(':');
                return dateTime.AddHours(Int32.Parse(offsetArgs[0]) * offsetSign).AddMinutes(Int32.Parse(offsetArgs[1]) * offsetSign);
            }
}
```

And when calling it from ItemController in MVC project

```
StartDate = new Helper().ConvertToSpecificTimeZone(properties.StartDate, this.UTCTimeOffset).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

and it sometime give error like

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: The added or subtracted value
>   results in an un-representable DateTime. Parameter name: value at
>   System.DateTime.AddTicks(Int64 value) at
>   Myproject.Utility.Helper.ConvertTimeZone(DateTime dateTime, String
>   timeOffset) at Myproject.Controllers.ItemController.Manage(String
>   param)

Please tell me how to handle this error in my code.

Comment: What are the `datatypes` of `properties.StartDate` and `this.UTCTimeOffset`?

Comment: datatypes of properties.StartDate is Datetime and this.UTCTimeOffset is string (-4)

Comment: And `ConvertTimeZone` is a `custom method` again?

Comment: yes convert time zone is custom method

Comment: Please add `ConvertTimeZone` method.

Comment: Please see the question, now I have mention the ConvertTimeZone  method

Comment: Is your datetime `01/01/0001 00:00:00` created by `new DateTime()` and do you pass negative timezone?

Comment: May be it happen sometime  and we pass negative value  like -4

Comment: Note that instead of using the `DateTime` struct you could use the [`DateTimeOffset` struct](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.aspx) which is a date-and-time value which knows its own offset from UTC (holds more info than a `DateTime` which only has a `Kind` indicating "local" or "utc", but "local" could be many different time zones). You will have access to methods like `ToOffset` which convert between time zones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that you have an unitialized datetime in properties.StartDate variable. 
Unitialized datetimes hold the value of 1/1/0001 12:00:00.

You can add this check on your ConvertTimeZone function to catch this kind of issues or/and try to fix your business logic flow.

```
        if (dateTime == default(DateTime))
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Please set the initial datetime value");
```

Comment: I think if we pass value utcDateTime=(1/1/0001 12:00:00) and utcOffset ="-04:00" then it not cause error.

Comment: I just opened a console application and typed the following. two lines of code. DateTime dt = default(DateTime); dt.AddHours(-4); It produces "System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: The added or subtracted value results in an un-representable DateTime"

Comment: OK, You are right I too get the error after applying default(DateTime). Thanks for your answer .